# Is my air pressure system okay?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, planets, hard-science, weather

Second question here. So in a previous question I got told to make a wind system to determine precipitation, which in turn needs and air pressure system. I've attached two images, the first is when its summer in the northern hemisphere, the second is summer in the southern hemisphere. Any feedback is appreciated! Oh and also, red is high pressure blue is low pressure.

[image: Northern Hemisphere Summer]
[image: Southern Hemisphere Summer]

Comment: That would be a very very strange world where you have a huge *stationary* low pressure area over a continent in summer... What is the proposed mechanism creating and maintaining such an area?

Comment: I tried to add this via a guide supplied to me in my first question. That clearly didn’t work out, so I’ll need further clarification on how this works/how to draw this out

Comment: My point was that you cannot really have a stationary long-term area of low pressure (or high pressure) at mid latitudes. Air is a fluid, and fluids tend to equilibrium. Say there is an area of low pressure over Bucharest; well, that means that air from the surrounding areas will flow in (this is called wind, or storm) and tend to equalize the pressure. (That's why when the barometer falls you know bad weather is coming.) The Sun pours energy into the system, which energy is transferred to the air in a non-uniform manner, so that temperature (and hence pressure) becomes unequal etc.

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues:

- areas of high and low pressure are necessarily adjacent. In your case you have quite large holes between them. It seems highly unlikely that there is a very large area with no pressure gradient.
- if it is summer in the north hemisphere, why would the large area of high pressure be in the southern hemisphere, and vice-versa for the summer in the south hemisphere?
- cyclones and anti-cyclones are never stationary, they move around. Your question it's like asking if a movie is good just by looking at a single frame of the entire movie.

Comment: As stated in another comment, I tried to follow a guide supplied to me, but clearly I did something wrong along the way. How would you suggest I change/draw this out?